# Can we insert or update FieldSets using apex code?

Tags: apex, force.com, fieldsets

Although we can create or update fieldsets using salesforce UI but Is there any way to insert or update FieldSets using apex code (using metadata or API calls) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is indeed possible via the [Salesforce Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_fieldset.htm). While this is a Web Service it is available through Apex like any other Web Service. There is a prebuilt Apex wrapper with samples [here](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi). The FieldSet metadata type can be used with the 'create' and  'update' operations on this API.

As if by magic it appears someone has just commited a FieldSet example to the library. Note that the Metadata API is an aysnc API, you can poll its results via Batch Apex or apex:actionPoller. Examples of doing both are included in the Github repo and Readme.

[Creating a FieldSet via Apex](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls#L492)...

```
    // FieldSet     
    MetadataService.FieldSet fieldSet = new MetadataService.FieldSet();
    fieldSet.fullName = 'Test__c.MyFieldSet';
    fieldSet.label = 'My FieldSet';
    fieldSet.description = 'Used by my VF page';
    MetadataService.FieldSetItem myAvailableField = new MetadataService.FieldSetItem();
    myAvailableField.field = 'TestField__c';
    myAvailableField.isFieldManaged = true;
    myAvailableField.isRequired = true;
    fieldSet.availableFields = new List<MetadataService.FieldSetItem>();
    fieldSet.availableFields.add(myAvailableField);

    // Create
    MetadataService.AsyncResult[] results = service.create(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { fieldSet });
```

[Updating a FieldSet via Apex](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls#L512)...

```
    // FieldSet     
    MetadataService.FieldSet fieldSet = new MetadataService.FieldSet();
    fieldSet.fullName = 'Test__c.MyFieldSet';
    fieldSet.label = 'My FieldSet';
    fieldSet.description = 'Used by my VF page';            
    MetadataService.FieldSetItem myAvailableField = new MetadataService.FieldSetItem();
    myAvailableField.field = 'TestField__c';
    myAvailableField.isFieldManaged = true;
    myAvailableField.isRequired = true;
    MetadataService.FieldSetItem myAvailableFieldNew = new MetadataService.FieldSetItem();
    myAvailableFieldNew.field = 'ExternalField__c';
    myAvailableFieldNew.isFieldManaged = true;
    myAvailableFieldNew.isRequired = true;
    fieldSet.availableFields = new List<MetadataService.FieldSetItem>();
    fieldSet.availableFields.add(myAvailableField);
    fieldSet.availableFields.add(myAvailableFieldNew);

    // Update
    List<MetadataService.UpdateMetadata> updateMetadataList = new List<MetadataService.UpdateMetadata>();
    updateMetadataList.add(new MetadataService.UpdateMetadata());
    updateMetadataList[0].currentName = 'Test__c.MyFieldSet';
    updateMetadataList[0].metadata = fieldSet;
    MetadataService.AsyncResult[] results = service.updateMetadata(updateMetadataList);
```

Comment: It's awesome Andrew. I will definitely give it a try. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @andrew can I add and remove fields from page layout by fieldSet ???

Comment: @Anzar, no fieldsets do not apply to layouts, sorry.

Comment: @AndrewFawcett thanks for the reply, actually I want to remove field from layout via metadata. I will be thankful to you if you just take a look here is the link of the question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140283/remove-field-from-page-layout-using-update-metadata?noredirect=1#comment202249_140283

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding fields in FieldSet as **displayedFields** rather than **availableFields**? Please see simple code below. Developer console throws an error for ***fieldSet.displayedFields.add(myAvailableField);***

Error Message: Metadata API Exception Attempt to de-reference a null object

```
// FieldSet     
MetadataService.FieldSet fieldSet = new MetadataService.FieldSet();
fieldSet.fullName = 'PricebookEntry.MyFieldSet1';
fieldSet.label = 'My FieldSet1';
fieldSet.description = 'Used by my VF page';

//FieldSet Field    
fieldSet.availableFields = new List<MetadataService.FieldSetItem>();
MetadataService.FieldSetItem myAvailableField = new MetadataService.FieldSetItem();
//Field 1
myAvailableField.field = 'UnitPrice';
fieldSet.availableFields.add(myAvailableField);
//Field 2
myAvailableField = new MetadataService.FieldSetItem();
myAvailableField.field = 'Product2.LastModifiedDate';
fieldSet.displayedFields.add(myAvailableField);

// Create   
List<MetadataService.UpsertResult> results = service.upsertMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { fieldSet });
```

Comment: Sonebody down voted and now that I look I can probably see why. But above post is related and valid if someone is looking for FieldSet + Apex. Not asking to change your opinion, but at same time wanted to voice mine as well :)