# Clone Field Set

Tags: metadata-api, fieldsets

Is it possible to Clone a Field Set?
I read [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16836/can-we-insert-or-update-fieldsets-using-apex-code) stack related to inserting and updating Field Set.  Can I apply the same principle? What I want to do is to:

- Allow User to Select Object
- Select Field Set Name
- Add new Field Set Name

I can get the Field from the Field Set.  Can I call the Metadata API and pass the Object, Fields, and new Field Set Name?  If there is an simpler means please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be as simple as you've described. Retrieve the field set metadata, update the fullName (and any other attributes), then use a create call to create the new metadata. This is basically the same process as it would be for cloning a record (except for which fields you'd update).

Comment: Thank you for the reply sfdxfox. In the MetadataServiceExamples Class(in link above) the Field Set Field is hard coded.  Can I pass a set that contains the fields from the source Field Set?  From the sample class :
MetadataService.FieldSetItem myAvailableField = new MetadataService.FieldSetItem();
myAvailableField.field = 'TestField__c';(Can I assign the Set here?)

Comment: @Phuc Yes, just set the fullName to whatever you need it to be.